# Перемешивание блоков с данными из БД при каждом обновлении страницы

Tags: php, html, mysql, случайные-числа

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать рандомное перемешивание блоков с данными из БД при каждом обновлении страницы.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 22";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<p>Имя:".$row['name']."</p><p>Фамилия:".$row['surname']."</p>";
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: `order by rand()` допишите в запрос да и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примените функцию http://www.php.su/shuffle() к массиву после функции mysqli_fetch_all  и в цикле простом выводите

---

**P.S.**
С использованием http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 22";
$rs = mysqli_query($link, $strSQL);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($rs);
shuffle($rows);
foreach($rows as $row)
    echo "<p>Имя:".$row['name']."</p><p>Фамилия:".$row['surname']."</p>";
mysqli_close();
```

Comment: в моем случае куда его приписать и как?

Comment: @AlievA. Дополнил кодом ответ. При этом стоит использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php

Comment: не работает, много ошибок

Comment: 1. Если ошибка говорит, что нет функций с префиксом mysqli_, то нужно в php.ini подключить драйвер msqli. 2. Если в ошибке говорится об отсутствии индекса массива, то распечатать массив функцией var_export и сверить название ключей массива, выводимого в цикле.

Comment: **P.S.** `ORDER BY rand()` красивый, но с точки зрения БД тяжелый способ. Вот пример, таблица _main_ имеет 5.5 млн. записей. Простой запрос `SELECT * FROM main where id > 200000 and id < 300000` количество записей 28842, время выполнения **0.0148 сек**. Запрос `SELECT * FROM main where id > 600000 and id < 700000 ORDER BY RAND()` - количество записей 25734, время **0.1357 сек**. Запрос `SELECT * FROM main order by rand()` - количество записей 5573801, время **27.4961 сек.**

Comment: @GIWhitefoot, человек всю выборку выводит на страницу, вряд ли там больше 10-15 значений может быть, так что в данном случае `rand()` не будет проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает)

Answer (score 2):

чтобы перемешать данные с минимальными затратами (изменениями кода) сделайте это на стороне БД изменив запрос

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 22 ORDER BY rand()";
```